# How to get core query Explore in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Here i have got JSON values from this i have used in query core explore but i got 0 value

```
{"kind":"analytics#gaData","id":"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:181407717&metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today","query":{"start-date":"7daysAgo","end-date":"today","ids":"ga:181407717","metrics":["ga:pageviews","ga:uniquePageviews"],"start-index":1,"max-results":1000},"itemsPerPage":1000,"totalResults":1,"selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:181407717&metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today","profileInfo":{"profileId":"181407717","accountId":"125404806","webPropertyId":"UA-125404806-1","internalWebPropertyId":"183966900","profileName":"All Web Site Data","tableId":"ga:181407717"},"containsSampledData":false,"columnHeaders":[{"name":"ga:pageviews","columnType":"METRIC","dataType":"INTEGER"},{"name":"ga:uniquePageviews","columnType":"METRIC","dataType":"INTEGER"}],"totalsForAllResults":{"ga:pageviews":"4","ga:uniquePageviews":"2"},"rows":[["4","2"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

> totalsForAllResults":{"ga:pageviews":"4","ga:uniquePageviews":"2"},"rows":[["4","2"]]}

Your request appears to returning results just fine.   if these aren't the numbers you were expecting then you may want to consider the following as you have added today in your request.

The Google analytics core reporting api is for extracting data from Google analytics it is not intended for extracting resent data from Google analytics as  It takes 24 - 48 hours for the data to be processed on the servers.

[Data latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

> Data processing latency
>   Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day.

Try doing the same request but do it for a few days ago.  or try  using the [Google antlyics realtime api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) which only displays the last five minutes of data give or take.

Comment: ok thanks ..but I want data .is any solution can please any suggestion

Comment: The data you want does not exist yet you cant have it until its completed processing wait until tomorrow then you can see todays data assuming there isnt that much traffic on your site.

Comment: I have doubt  website runing in online but my python code  run in locally.then how to display the data in after two days .i didnot understand .can you explain.first time work on google analytics.please help me .I am struggling you told concept.

Comment: if your code isn't returning any data then there is none for that request.

Comment: but my code is returning this type of data.u see my data in top for json format

Comment: You are getting data so what exactly is your problem it looks like its working fine

Comment: sorry..once my code is working fine .I ping ti sir..sorry sir

Comment: I got the data but that data using to how to create a chart give me any example code